# Create a procedure in MariaDB v10.1.xx

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mariadb-10.1

Mám dotaz SQL pro reindexování sloupce ID.

```
SET @ newid = 0;
UPDATE tablename SET id = (@ newid: = @ newid + 1) ORDER BY id;
```

Tento dotaz SQL funguje správně.
Pokouším se zahrnout tento dotaz SQL do uložené procedury.

```
ODDĚLOVAČ //
VYTVOŘTE POSTUP reindex
(
      V par VARCHAR (50)
)
ZAČÍT

SET @ newid = 0;
UPDATE dbName.par SET id = (@ newid: = @ newid + 1) ORDER BY id;

KONEC //
ODDĚLOVAČ ;
```

Postup je vytvořen a uložen. K problému dochází při volání procedury.

```
CALL reindex (souhrn);
```

Kde 'souhrn' je název tabulky.
Volání uložené procedury „reindex“ se vrací:

> \ # 1054 - Neznámý sloupec 'souhrn' v 'seznamu polí'

Nevím, proč se procedura vrací „Neznámý sloupec“, když je procedura aplikována na konkrétní „jméno_tabulky“. Mám někde chybu? Děkuji mnohokrát.

Comment: Table names are not strings. You would have to use PREPARE and EXECUTE to do this for any table name.

Comment: But you shouldn't be renumbering your id column anyway. Id values should be unique, but they aren't required to be consecutive values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use dynamic SQL to create the `UPDATE` query inside your procedure and then `PREPARE` and `EXECUTE` it:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE reindex
(
    IN par VARCHAR(50)
)
BEGIN
    SET @newid=0;
    SET @sql = CONCAT('UPDATE dbName.', par, ' SET id=(@newid:=@newid+1) ORDER BY id');
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=7d1db6afc83978dc98ae318c90fcd3af)